# how to input this command line

Tags: command-line, options

```
hume@linux-o1dm:~> gnomesu -u legum java -jar '/home/legum/frem/frem.jar'
Unknown option -jar
```

I want `-u` for `gnomesu` and `-jar` for `java`, but the openSUSE treat `-u -jar` only for `gnomesu`.

What is the correct way of putting this on the command-line?

Answer (score 5):

Try quotes this way:

```
gnomesu -u legum "java -jar '/home/legum/frem/frem.jar'"
```

or (not sure `gnomesu` supports this):

```
gnomesu -u legum -- java -jar '/home/legum/frem/frem.jar'
```

Many commands interpret `--` as end of options, start of arguments

Comment: Either should work.